# Trying to build a SQL SELECT query that displays users who occur the most

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

As mentioned in the title, I'm struggling to find a SQL query that would display all users' nicknames (from Users table) with 3 most common ratings AND their number of ratings, sorted by their occurence in the Ratings table.

The tables:

```
1. Users  
+========+==========+  
| userID | userName |  
+--------+----------+  
|   1    |  User1   |  
|   2    |  User2   |  
|   3    |  User3   |  
|   4    |  User4   |  
|   5    |  User5   |  
|   6    |  User6   |  
+========+==========+


2. Ratings (the rating column is irrelevant)  
+========+========+  
| userID | rating |  
+--------+--------+  
|   1    |   5    |  
|   3    |   4    |  
|   5    |   2    |  
|   1    |   5    |  
|   5    |   3    |  
|   4    |   6    |  
|   2    |   2    |  
|   1    |   4    |  
|   5    |   5    |  
|   2    |   1    |  
|   4    |   3    |  
|   5    |   1    |
+========+========+
```

The result of the query would be:

```
User5 4  
User1 3  
User2 2  
User4 2
```

Here's my progress so far, though it displays the users without the values and unsorted, probably not the correct way:

```
SELECT userName  
FROM Users  
WHERE userID  
IN(  
    SELECT userID s  
    FROM Ratings s  
    WHERE (  
        SELECT count( userID )  
        FROM Ratings  
        WHERE userID = s.userID  
        ) >= (  
            SELECT COUNT( userID ) AS number  
            FROM Ratings  
            GROUP BY userID  
            ORDER BY number DESC  
            LIMIT 1  
            OFFSET 3  
    )  
)
```

I'd appreciate any help, be it the complete query or just a tip. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: can you please tag the rdbms?

Comment: @Teja I mentioned it in the post "The result of the query would be:"

Comment: @StephanLechner Woops, sorry. I posted the query that was fit to my own base. It's fixed now. Also tagged it.

Comment: You mention "with 3 most ratings AND their number of ratings". What does 3 most ratings mean? This is especially confusing because you also mention "rating column is irrelevant"...

Comment: @Anand With the largest number of occurences in the table. The User5 (userID 5) is the most common one in the table, occuring 4 times in total.

Comment: Still struggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I just posted the answer, but thanks.

Comment: Hm. Well, if you say so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I worked it out, guys:

```
SELECT userName
FROM Users u
WHERE u.userID
IN (
    SELECT userID
    FROM Ratings r
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT( userID ) AS number
        FROM Ratings
        GROUP BY userID
        ORDER BY number DESC
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET 3
    ) <= (
        SELECT count( userID )
        FROM Ratings
        WHERE userID = r.userID
    )
)
ORDER BY (
    SELECT count( userID )
    FROM Ratings
    WHERE userID = u.userID
) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Z.* FROM
  (
    SELECT u.UserName,
           COUNT( * ) AS NoOfOccurences
      FROM Users u
      JOIN 
           Ratings r
        ON u.userID = r.userID
     GROUP BY u.UserName
  ) Z
     ORDER BY Z.NoOfOccurences DESC;
```

Comment: I managed to achieve that as well but.. It displays ALL the occurences instead of the 3 most common ones.

Comment: Just add a ```limit 3``` after the order by clause.

Comment: This just limits the results to 3 rows.

Comment: What do you mean by 3 most common ones?